# Spring Aop - for standalone applications

Tags: java, spring, interceptor, spring-aop

I am calling main method of multiple standalone java applications from shell scripts.

Now, how to apply before and after method interceptor for each call?

I tried Spring aop, but for that I need to change main method of each standalone appilation to create object using spring context.

Is it possible to apply interceptor without changing the code in exisitng Standalone application.

Comment: I am looking for solution like creating a class with static method that will initialize the spring context. I tried this, but it didn't work. If I have to change in each standalone class then it will be lot of change as I have to do changes in more than 50 classes.

Comment: The only possible solution is to wrap the application in a new application and apply aspect on it. If you can't do that it's not possible.